# Calculating Angular momentum of given problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, rigid-body-dynamics

**Question**
[image]

**Attempt**

[image]

But by my method the answer comes out in terms of M ( mass of pulley) which not given. Where am I wrong? Also do provide alternate solution or suggestion.
Please help.

Comment: Moment of inertia is wrong

Comment: Yeah My mistake i thought pulley as a ring

Comment: As I recall, the net torque acting on a system gives the rate of change of the angular momentum.  In this case mgR = dL/dt and L = mgRt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular velocity does depend on the mass of the pulley $M$. Just think about it intuitively, if the pulley had a negligible mass with respect to the mass $m$ then the acceleration of the system would be that of gravity; on the other hand, if $M$ was so big that $m$ could be negligible the system wouldn't accelerate at all. Still, it is strange that the problem doesn't specify the mass of the pulley to be $M$.

By the way, the momentum of inertia of the disk around that axis is $I=\frac{1}{2}MR^2.$

Comment: In solution he has integrated gravitys's torque and written the ans as mgRt. But that would include rotational momentum of pulley right?

Comment: I don't quite get what you mean, but as a comment noted above, the problem asks about the angular momentum, not the angular velocity as you and I misunderstood, so you should only integrate the torque and that would be it. This result, which corresponds to the angular momentum doesn't depend on $M$, but the angular velocity does. Sorry for the misunderstanding.